# ¿Como hacer una validacion alfanumerica en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, web

Buenas,estoy intentando hacer que el usuario tenga que ingresar si o si al menos un numero o una letra,caso contrario que de error.

```js
//Caracteres permitidos
var letras = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var numeros = "0123456789";
var correcto = 0;
var correctonum = 0;

//Formulario
var password = document.createElement("form");
password.action = "";
password.method = "POST";
password.id = "formulario";
password.onsubmit = "return envio()";

//Ingreso de contraseña
var entrada = document.createElement("input");
entrada.type = "text";
entrada.name = "password";
entrada.id = "pass";
entrada.placeholder = "Ingrese su contraseña";

//boton
var boton = document.createElement("input");
boton.type = "submit";
boton.value = "Enviar";
boton.onclick = contra;

//div que contiene todo
var contenido = document.createElement("div");
contenido.id = "contenido";

//Añadir todo al HTML
document.body.appendChild(contenido);
contenido.appendChild(password);
contenido.appendChild(entrada);
contenido.appendChild(boton);

//Funcion para saber si la contraseña es correcta
function contra() {
    entrada.value.toLowerCase;
    for (var i = 0; i < entrada.value.length; i++) {
        correcto = 0;
        correctonum = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < letras.length; j++) {
            if (letras.charAt(j) == entrada.value.charAt(i)) {
                correcto++;
            }
            if (correcto == 0) {
                alert("error,debe introducir al menos una letra");
                return false;
            }
        }
        for (var l = 0; l < numeros.length; l++) {
            if (numeros.charAt(l) == entrada.value.charAt(i)) {
                correctonum++;
            }
            if (correctonum == 0) {
                alert("error,debe introducir al menos un numero");
                return false;
            }
        }


        return true;
    }
}

function envio() {

    if (requerido(entrada)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("vuelva a intentarlo");
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Ejercicio 1</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <script src="ejercicio1_ext.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El error que tengo es que la letra ingresada no puede ser un numero si es una letra o al revés,por eso siempre va a tirar un error.
Cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que haya al menos un carácter que sea dígito o letra deberías realizar la comprobación de si la cadena es correcta o no una vez hayas recorrido todos los caracteres de la entrada:

```js
//Caracteres permitidos
var letras = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var numeros = "0123456789";
var correcto = 0;
var correctonum = 0;

//Formulario
var password = document.createElement("form");
password.action = "";
password.method = "POST";
password.id = "formulario";
password.onsubmit = "return envio()";

//Ingreso de contraseña
var entrada = document.createElement("input");
entrada.type = "text";
entrada.name = "password";
entrada.id = "pass";
entrada.placeholder = "Ingrese su contraseña";

//boton
var boton = document.createElement("input");
boton.type = "submit";
boton.value = "Enviar";
boton.onclick = contra;

//div que contiene todo
var contenido = document.createElement("div");
contenido.id = "contenido";

//Añadir todo al HTML
document.body.appendChild(contenido);
contenido.appendChild(password);
contenido.appendChild(entrada);
contenido.appendChild(boton);

//Funcion para saber si la contraseña es correcta
function contra() {
    for (var i = 0; i < entrada.value.length; i++) {
        correcto = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < letras.length; j++) {
            if (letras.charAt(j) == entrada.value.charAt(i)) {
                correcto++;
            }
        }
        for (var l = 0; l < numeros.length; l++) {
            if (numeros.charAt(l) == entrada.value.charAt(i)) {
                correcto++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (correcto == 0) {
      alert("error,debe introducir al menos un número o una letra");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function envio() {

    if (requerido(entrada)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("vuelva a intentarlo");
    }

}
```

Aunque este parece un caso claro para usar expresiones regulares:

```js
//Formulario
var password = document.createElement("form");
password.action = "";
password.method = "POST";
password.id = "formulario";
password.onsubmit = "return envio()";

//Ingreso de contraseña
var entrada = document.createElement("input");
entrada.type = "text";
entrada.name = "password";
entrada.id = "pass";
entrada.placeholder = "Ingrese su contraseña";

//boton
var boton = document.createElement("input");
boton.type = "submit";
boton.value = "Enviar";
boton.onclick = contra;

//div que contiene todo
var contenido = document.createElement("div");
contenido.id = "contenido";

//Añadir todo al HTML
document.body.appendChild(contenido);
contenido.appendChild(password);
contenido.appendChild(entrada);
contenido.appendChild(boton);

// Caracteres permitidos
var caracteres = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/;

//Funcion para saber si la contraseña es correcta
function contra() {
  var valido = caracteres.test(entrada.value);
  if (!valido){
    alert('Debe introducir al menos una letra o un número');    
  }
  return valido;
}

function envio() {

    if (requerido(entrada)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("vuelva a intentarlo");
    }

}
```

Eso sí, si lo que pretendes es que únicamente se introduzcan caracteres y números entonces bastaría con cambiar la expresión regular:

```js
    //Formulario
    var password = document.createElement("form");
    password.action = "";
    password.method = "POST";
    password.id = "formulario";
    password.onsubmit = "return envio()";

    //Ingreso de contraseña
    var entrada = document.createElement("input");
    entrada.type = "text";
    entrada.name = "password";
    entrada.id = "pass";
    entrada.placeholder = "Ingrese su contraseña";

    //boton
    var boton = document.createElement("input");
    boton.type = "submit";
    boton.value = "Enviar";
    boton.onclick = contra;

    //div que contiene todo
    var contenido = document.createElement("div");
    contenido.id = "contenido";

    //Añadir todo al HTML
    document.body.appendChild(contenido);
    contenido.appendChild(password);
    contenido.appendChild(entrada);
    contenido.appendChild(boton);

    // Caracteres permitidos
    var caracteres = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

    //Funcion para saber si la contraseña es correcta
    function contra() {
      var valido = caracteres.test(entrada.value);
      if (!valido){
        alert('Debe introducir únicamente letras o números');    
      }
      return valido;
    }

    function envio() {

        if (requerido(entrada)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("vuelva a intentarlo");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar algo como esto

```
function soloLetrasYNum(campo) {
 var validos = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
 var letra;
 var bien = true;
 for (var i=0; i<campo.value.length; i++) {
  letra=campo.value.charAt(i).toLowerCase()
  if (validos.indexOf(letra) == -1){bien=false;};
  }
  if (!bien) {
  alert("Error. Caracteres no aceptados");
 campo.focus();
}
}
```